# I want to loop this, and everytime it loops I want +1 so it prints ( 1 2 3.. untill infinite) But it prints 2 1 2 1 2 ... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, loops, math

I want to loop this, and everytime it loops I want +1 so it prints ( 1 2 3 4 5.. untill infinite)
But it prints 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
what am i doing wrong?
code:

```
import time
x = 1

def main():
    print(x)    
    x + 1 
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x+1)
     
main()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says main does -> print 1, 2, sleep, print 2.

You should do

```
x = 1
def main():
    while true:
        print(x)
        x += 1
        time.sleep(1)


main()
```

Your original code doesn't alter x. x += 1 means x = x + 1.

x + 1 is just 2. And that 2 doesn't get stored anywhere. And to go on infinitely you just leave a while true loop running and manually kill the code. Although you could put some cap on it like 1000 loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator.
By using `next()` you can ask it what the next number would be and they only get calculated once you actually need them. The limit ist the system size of python-integers in this example.

```
import sys
maxSize = sys.maxsize

i = iter(range(maxSize))

def main():
    print(next(i))

main()
# 0

main()
# 1

main()
# 2
```

Comment: thank you, i am learning alot

Comment: @Arthur glad I could help. If you find an answer helpful you can upvote it, the answer author gets then a few points. The most helpful answer you can also "accept" which  closes the question, helps future readers and awards the answer author and yourself a few points. Happy coding!

Comment: I dont have 15 reputation so i can not upvote but i will accept, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is that you're restarting x every time you're caling the function main() beccause there is no loop.

```
def main():
x = 1
while True:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
    x += 1

main()
```

Comment: I thought main was the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function when you are adding `x+1` you are not storing the value back in x to update it. Here is a better implementation.

```
import time

x = 1


def main():
    global x
    print(x)
    x += 1
    time.sleep(1)


while True:
    main()
```

Comment: No problem, Accept my reply as the answer and also upvote it : )

Comment: i dont have 15 reputation so i can not upvote :(

Comment: just accept it as answer then : )

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the best answer

```
import time #importing time

def infinitive_loop(): #define new function
    x = 1 #making variable x equals 1
    while True: #this is the loop
        yield x
        time.sleep(1)#wait 1 sec.
        x += 1#it increases one every time

for x in infinitive_loop():
    print(x)#print "x"
```

Comment: I am learning alot, thank you